# Are substitutions allowed in curling?

Tags: rules, curling

Most curling teams has an alternate players.
Are the substitutions allowed during a match?

I mean in those cases:

- injury of a player
- technical choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teams may substitute a player for injury, but not for technical choice.

R3 (d) clearly allows for a "qualified alternate" in the case of "a player being unable to continue, and details what will occur.

> Where  a  player  is  unable  to  continue  to  play  in  a  game,  the  team  may either:
>
> ...
>
> (ii)  bring  in  a  qualified  alternate  at  the  beginning  of  an  end,  in  which case  the  delivery  rotation  and  the  skip  and  vice-skip  positions  may be  changed  (the  revised  rotation  of  play  applying  for  the remainder  of  that  game),  and  the  replaced  player  may  not  reenter  the  game.

R3 (f) further limits the number of alternates to one (1) per team, or none of competition does not allow it.